# Finding two integers to equal 26

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, pigeonhole-principle

> Show that if any 14 integers are selected from the set $S = \{1,2,3,...,25\}$, then there are at least two whose sum is 26.

Let there be finite sets $A, B, C $.
$A=\{ X| X\in\mathcal{P}(S)$ and $|X|=14 \}$ 
$B=\{ X| X\in\mathcal{P}(S)$ and $|X|=2 \}$
$C=\{ X| X\in\mathcal{P}(S)$ and $|X|=2$ and $x_1+x_2=26, x_1,x_2\in X\}$

Then, $C \subseteq B $.  $C$ is nonempty because  $\{1, 25\}\in C$.  $|A|=\binom {25}{14}= 4457400$
 $|B|=\binom {25}{2}=300$
Since $|A| >|B|$ and $|B| >=|C|, |A|>|C|$.  Thus, the function $f: A\rightarrow C $
is not injective by the pigeonhole principle.  Suppose $A_1=A_2, A_1, A_2 \in A$.  Then $f(A_1)\neq f(A_2)$ because f is not injective.

I am kind of stuck on the proof now.  If you choose any subset in A, then how do you ensure that the corresponding subset in C contains elements of A?  Is this even the right approach to the proof?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have at most one number in each of the following 13 boxes. The 14th gives you two in one box, and you have your result.

1,25 | 2,24 | 3,23 | ... | 12,14 | 13

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

consider sets$$(1,25),(2,24),...,(12,14),(13)$$

by pp we have atleast one pair from the same box hence the sum would be $26$